# Multiple Independent transactions in single stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, sql-server-2012

I have to insert and delete from multiple tables and I wanted to do all these in one single stored procedure so can I have the multiple transactions blocks as below and what would be the best way to handle errors in each transaction.Please advise

```
      BEGIN TRANSACTION [TRANS1]
     BEGIN TRY
 Insert into  ArchiveTable select * from Completed (nolock) 

 delete from Completed(nolock) where convert(date,LastModified,101) > getdate() 
 COMMIT TRANSACTION [TRANS1]
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [TRANS1]
PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() 
 END CATCH
```

---

```
     BEGIN TRANSACTION [TRANS2]
     BEGIN TRY
 Insert into  ArchiveTable2 select * from New (nolock) 

 delete from New (nolock) where convert(date,LastModified,101) > getdate() 
 COMMIT TRANSACTION [TRANS2]
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [TRANS2]
PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() 
 END CATCH
```

Comment: Sample transaction blocks are independent, you can do that. Question is - what you're gonna do to committed transactions if error happens in following blocks? And deleting with `nolock` is a nice one...

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know the best way to handle errors in the independent transactions and want to keep them all in one stored procedure..is that possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible.